# TFS search code under path and combine scopes

Tags: tfs, code-search

I am trying to search TFS 2018 using [code search feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/code-search?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for some text (.NET version in this case) in all config files for a given project or path but it only works without `path:` or `proj:` scope returning results from entire repository.

For example `NETFramework,Version=v ext:config` returns results for all config files in entire repository as expected but if I add a `path:` or `proj:` scope as well or even remove `ext:` scope and use only `path:` or `proj:` nothing is returned.

Given folder structure similar to this `$/Root/A001/Sandbox/user/ProjName` how can you use `path:` or `proj:` scope to search only within ProjName folder?

None of the code search [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/advanced-code-search-syntax?view=vsts#functions-to-select-projects-repositories-paths-and-files) combine scopes. Is that even possible?

Here is some of the stuff I tried and none of it works:

```
NETFramework,Version=v ext:config path:Root/A001/Sandbox/user/ProjName

NETFramework,Version=v ext:config path:$/Root/A001/Sandbox/user/ProjName

NETFramework,Version=v ext:config path:A001/Sandbox/user/ProjName

NETFramework,Version=v ext:config proj:ProjName

NETFramework,Version=v path:Root/A001/Sandbox/user/ProjName
```